# Select People and Groups dialog is having wrong format on IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I am working on a Sharepoint web application and  i have created a site column of type “People or Group”. Which will automatically be associated with the following user selection dialog:-

[image]

But as shown in the above picture the dialog will not be showing the users as the box is very small !! can anyone advice how to fix this problem. I am using IE 10 64x , while if I used Firefox it will show the dialog correctly.

now using IE developer tool I changed the height for the resultcontent from 45px to be 350px and it expand the username area well, but when I write the following inside my custom css file , it did not have any effect:-

```
#resultcontent

{

height:350px;

}
```

Can anyone advice on this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when overriding inline styles for sharepoint you need to use !important

try:

```
#resultcontent{height:350px !important;}
```

Comment: i already tried this  but without having any effect, even using F12 developer tool there is not any effect for my customCSS file on the popup... i think this is the problem the popuo is having different CSS master page